# Why is empty AdS identified with CFT vacuum and what do excited states correspond to?

Tags: string-theory, research-level, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I have a few questions regarding the AdS/CFT dictionary regarding the state-state map.
I have seen people identifying the empty AdS spacetime with a CFT vacuum.

1. What do they mean by "empty" AdS? Is it
   i. AdS spacetime without considering any dynamical field  or
   ii. empty AdS *geometry* as in no black holes are to be embedded in the AdS, but dynamical fields are there?

In the case (i) is true, what is even meant by vacuum on the AdS side? In case (ii) is true and there are scalar fields propagating in the AdS, how can it correspond to the original CFT vacuum given that the non-normalizable modes of the bulk scalar deform the CFT?

2. I know that the GKPW dictionary states $Z_{\text{CFT}}=Z_{\text{bulk}}$, but this is only an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces: what makes us say that the CFT vacuum is identified with the AdS vacuum and not some excited state on the AdS side? What is the precise form of the isomorphism in the GKPW dictionary *for states*? If there exists none, what is the 
   i. "intuitive" argument for the identification of vacuua generically in AdS/CFT and 
   ii. argument in the case of Maldacena's Type IIB string theory on AdS$_5 \times S^5$ dual to $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM case?
3. Finally, what is the AdS dual of the undeformed CFT excited states: 
   i. Are they the normalizable modes of the bulk scalar field or 
   ii. Are there some black hole configurations embedded in AdS but no scalar field considered?

I suspect the former because the [HKLL](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0606141) map is a promise to do so, but the latter might also be true because of Maldacena's identification of eternal AdS black hole with a thermofield double state on the CFT side. In the case the former is true, what is the dual of black hole geometries which are asymptotically AdS: do they necessarily correspond to *mixed* states unlike the CFT vacuum and the excited states are? In case the latter is true, again what would be the meaning of vacuum on the AdS side?

Most of the AdS/CFT reviews I have seen so far use the dictionary for operator mapping and the state map is kinda implicit. Any reference which clarifies the state map would also be welcome.

Comment: Aren't there too many questions being asked at once? Maybe condense the questions into more general questions, which would make the questions very clear at a first glance. I think most of what you are asking is revolving around the vacuum state correspondence, for which I would suggest Liu and Leutheusser's paper. Is that what it is? See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27078/ for the vacuum question.

Comment: Actually there are three questions labelled 1, 2 and 3. The subparts are actually possible answers to these questions, but not actual questions! The questions 1, 2 and 3 are logically related so I asked them altogether in one post. The first asks about the meaning of "empty AdS", the 2nd asks about why is the identification of vacuua made and the third asks the same about excited states. If you still think that it will be better if these should be asked differently, let me know and I will edit. And, Thanks for the reference, I will have a look at it.

Comment: Apart from Motl's comment in the post, the discussion in the link is surely related but not exactly what I am asking. But yes that comment partially answers my 2.(i), I would like to see an expansion of his comment: If two theories are physically equivalent why should the vacuua match? I mean, there _can_ be a non-trivial isomorphism too right?

Comment: Well, I just opened phys.SE to see that this post has not received any answers. I will try to answer some of these questions soon